# Suppressing variable name in tooltip generated by ggplotly

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

When I use `plotly::ggplotly` to convert a `ggplot2` graphic to an interactive `plotly` graphic, I don't want to use `text=` in the `ggplotly2` aesthetic because that creates the "empty group" problem for some setups.  So've I've focused on using the `label` aesthetic instead. This works fine in all contexts except that `ggplotly` is inserting the name of the variable in the front of the tooltip text:

```
require(ggplot2)
require(plotly)
d <- data.frame(x=1:10, y=10:1, z=letters[1:10])
ggplotly(ggplot(d, aes(x=x, y=y, label=z)) + geom_point(), tooltip='label')
```

In this case you'll see `z:` at the beginning of the tooltip hover text.  Is there a way to suppress the `z:`?

Comment: a dirty hack... but if `g` is your `g <- ggplotly(...)` then `g$x$data[[1]]$text <- gsub("z: ", "", g$x$data[[1]]$text)` seems to do the trick (there may be something in the docs; I've not looked)

Comment: That did it.  Thanks!  When using faceting so that multiple panels are produced I needed to do this: 
ggp <- function(obj) {
  g <- ggplotly(obj, tooltip='label')
 d <- g$x$data
 for(i in 1 : length(d)) {
   w <- d[[i]]$text
    if(length(w)) g$x$data[[i]]$text <- gsub('z: ', '', w)
  }
 g
 }